# How do I add cache-control response headers to index.html and static JS bundles created by Webpack in Springboot application?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cache-control

Basically, I have springboot application serving my index.html and other static JS files which includes(runtime, vendor, main) chunks created during the production build by Webpack. How do I set cache-control settings for index.html and chunks separately so that index.html won't be cached and chunks will be cached on the client-side? Currently, I have my resources under `static` folder like the following:

```
├── static
│   ├── index.html
|   |-- bundles
│   │   ├── main.js
│   │   ├── vendors.js
│   │   ├── runtime.js
```

`
Basically, I am aiming for long-term caching of static assets on the client-side.

Answer (score -1):

I interpret your question as asking how you can control this in Spring.

I think the better way to achieve what you want is to let Webpack output the different chunk-names so that they are cached for a long time (or until you deploy a new version of a chunk), not by specifically setting cache related headers for each filename.

The [Webpack caching documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) recommends outputting the different chunk filenames to also include the `contenthash`.

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "bundle.[contenthash].js",
  }
```

This will name your current `bundle.js` to something like `bundle.7b4c86b268840bec8c4d.js`. The first time a browser visits your site it will cache that chunk for a long time, typically a year but it depends on your configuration.

When you make changes to whatever code goes into `bundle.[contenthash].js`, the value of `contenthash` will change and the browser will cache that new version of your site/bundle since the filename doesn't match the cached bundle filename any more.

For more information, please refer to the aforementioned [Webpack caching documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/)